# How can I resolve a timeout using Azure Data Factory (ADF) when connecting to MySQL?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from a MySQL database to Azure SQL Server but I am getting a timeout error:

> Operation on target Copy MyTable failed:
> ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectOdbcSource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR
> [08001] [Microsoft][MySQL] (1004) The connection has timed out while
> connecting to server: xxxxx.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com at
> port:
> 1234.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
> [08001] [Microsoft][MySQL] (1004) The connection has timed out while
> connecting to server: xxxxx.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com at
> port: 1234.,Source=,'

I can preview data while looking at the source of my Copy Data task. There is no timeout. I see all of the rows and columns. I even changed the query to limit the results to 2 rows.

```
SELECT mytable.id, mytable.name FROM myschema.mytable LIMIT 2;
```

However, when I publish the pipeline and trigger it to run I get the timeout error. How can I resolve the timeout using Azure Data Factory (ADF) when connecting to MySQL?

Comment: What's the version of your MySQL? Have you set GLOBAL wait_timeout ?

Comment: It is MySQL Community engine version 5.7.26 hosted on AWS RDS. The GLOBAL wait_timeout is 28800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was not the most helpful. I discovered what the problem was. The problem was that the IP Addresses used by ADF had to be added to the "Outbound IP" list from AWS MySQL. Everything started working once I updated the outbound IP address list.